# .NET console application: Is it possible to get a string located at specific coordinates on the console window?

Tags: .net, console-application

I'd like to get the string value from whatever string is at a specific location on the console window.  For example, if I have this on my console screen:

```
abcdefgh
ijklmnop
qrstuvwx
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

`string s = Console.GetString(1,2,4);`

This would return `klmn`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Looking for something like the [console screen buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Copies a number of characters from consecutive cells of a console screen buffer, beginning at a specified location.

---

**Example:**

```
private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

public static string GetString(Int16 y, Int16 x, uint length)
{
    var characters = new StringBuilder(1);
    uint numberOfCharactersRead;

    if (ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), characters, length,  new Coord(x, y), out numberOfCharactersRead))
        return characters.ToString();

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not get chars");
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, [Out] StringBuilder lpCharacter, uint length, Coord bufferCoord, out uint lpNumberOfCharactersRead);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Coord
{
    public short X;
    public short Y;

    public Coord(short x, short y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("abcdefgh");
    Console.WriteLine("ijklmnop");
    Console.WriteLine("qrstuvwx");

    string s = GetString(1, 2, 4);
    // 's' is now 'klmn'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReadConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which allows you to specify coordinates for the read.

The C# definitions can be found here (including an example): http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.readconsoleoutput